# bootstrap 3 input-group 100% width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In the bootstrap documentation, they have input groups that span 100% width with no additional markup: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
</div>
```

**I can't seem to get my input groups to span 100% without explicitly defining `width: 100%` on `input-group`.** Note that I've slightly adjusted the markup:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Auto width" />
    <div class="clear">
        <a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear { display: table-cell; }
```

I've created a fiddle to represent this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/B9LMN/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adding `width: 1%` to the input element's sibling fixes this:

```
.clear { width: 1%; display: table-cell; }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/B9LMN/2/

Comment: what kind of sorcery is this!

Comment: This answer does not explain why it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 11):

`input-group` has `display: table` css property, while the `<input class="form-control"` has `display: table-cell` css property.

```
<div class="input-group"> <!-- this is display: table -->
  <input type="text" class="form-control"> <!-- this is display: table-cell -->
  <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span> <!-- this is display: table-cell -->
</div>
```

According to [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/), under "Important Style Rules for Tables",

```
Width works on table cells just about how you would think it does, except when there is 
some kind of conflict. For instance if you tell the table itself to be 400px wide then the 
first cell of a three-cell row to be 100px wide and leave the others alone, that first cell
will be 100px wide and the other two will split up the remaining space.
```

it explains that if the `width` of the child element that has `table-cell` is defined (let's say `width: 100px`), then the next child element with `table-cell` property, although not defined, **will fill in the rest of the space.**

Comment: Very good explanation, thanks. Do we have a bootstrap class made specifically to fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

One way to get an `input-group` to stretch to full width seem to give one of its `input-group-addon` 100% width:

```
<div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
  <span class="one input-group-addon">one</span>
  <span class="two input-group-addon">two</span>
  <span class="tre input-group-addon" style="width:100%">tre</span> <!-- here -->
  <span class="for input-group-addon">for</span>
  <span class="fiv input-group-addon">fiv</span>
  <span class="input-group-btn"> 
     <button class="btn" type="button">x</button> 
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<h3>Form widths</h3>

<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Auto width</label>

    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Auto width" /> <span class=
      "input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>100% width</label>

    <div class="input-group" style="width: 100%">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="100% width" /> <span class=
      "input-group-addon"><a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to apply the `input-group-addon` styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you have select2 as a part of your "input-group", you better create it with "resolve" parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myselect").select2({ width: 'resolve' });           
});
```