# Input-group class in bootstrap does not allow any other element on same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is the code of Bootstrap which does not show properly the next element

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" id="my-checkbox"/></div>
                <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                    <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                    </span>
                    <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" />
                </div>                   
                <div class="col-md-5">Hi</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have used the suggestion given in [bootstrap 3 input-group 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436430/bootstrap-3-input-group-100-width) but it is not working

Comment: You can't have `.col-md-12>.col-md-2` You're missing an intervening level of `.row`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="input-group date form_datetime">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

i have moved col-md-5 to a new parent div. please see the [example](http://www.bootply.com/Sj0ydicD9W)